# Promise rejection (Network Error)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using axios to fetch a basic JSON data but keep on getting this error:

```
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0): Network Error
```

Now since that error itself was not "as much" useful to know what's going on I changed my code block and used `.catch`.

Error:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:82235:11)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:82107:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:10284:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25988:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25836:6)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25930:52
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:9523:23)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7339:34)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7216:8
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7155:1)
```

The code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok){
                console.log(response.statusText);
            }
            console.log((response))
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("ok")
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else faces this problem, I managed to fix it by adding `.done();` at the end of the Promise chain.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return response inside your first then statement otherwise the chaining will not work.

```js
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok){
                console.log(response.statusText);
            }
            console.log((response))
            
            // return response
            return response;
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("ok")
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Hope this helps.